# How to retain focus on one Window in Multithreaded Win32 App

Tags: winapi, mfc

Is there any way of keeping the focus set on one window always in Win32 or MFC even if some other windows try to steal it in other thread or in the same GUI thread..

Comment: If they are windows in your own application that are stealing the focus, you should be able to *fix* your code so that doesn't happen. If the user explicitly *sets* focus to another window, well then they should be allowed to do that.

Comment: Actually due to some requirements the window which is taking the focus is not visible to the user. And this problem is not coming always..It seems that it is a race condition in which, the window which is being created last would keep the foucs..

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to try and fix a race condition by introducing another race condition. You need to figure out why that other window is attempting to steal the focus when it isn't even visible. As far as I'm aware, non-visible windows can't *have* the focus.

Comment: Non-visible windows can have focus. For example, during WM_INITDIALOG handling, the dialog is not yet visible but you can call SetFocus on a child control. Naturally the expectation is that this is a transient state and you will be showing the dialog soon. But the original statement stands: figure out what that other window is doing.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Ok, I will try to find it..

Comment: But actual problem is both are in different threads and processing messages independently to each other..One issue which I can see is as windows will be created in active state so whichever would be created later  keep focus..

Comment: Ask yourself, ["What would the world be like if this were possible?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx). Sorry @RaymondChen :p